# How to solve renderer failed when use Grafana image renderer

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I install Grafana following from

https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-image-renderer/

and try to convert PNG from panel in Dashboard but i got this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM2an.png)

> custom-config-grafana-1   | logger=rendering renderer=http
> t=2023-03-16T04:03:14.362247294Z level=error msg=“Failed to send
> request to remote rendering service” error=“Get
> \“http://localhost:8081/render?deviceScaleFactor=1.000000&domain=localhost&encoding=&height=500&renderKey=eAVUw8ofFXRoq03ZzV7ZjB99wlohVbCD&timeout=60&timezone=Asia%2FBangkok&url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fd-solo%2FVTwajYaVz%2Fhome%3ForgId%3D1%26from%3D1678917792848%26to%3D1678939392848%26panelId%3D123125%26width%3D1000%26height%3D500%26tz%3DAsia%252FBangkok%26render%3D1&width=1000\“:
> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8081: connect: connection refused”
> custom-config-grafana-1   | logger=context userId=1 orgId=1
> uname=admin t=2023-03-16T04:03:14.377961211Z level=error
> msg=“Rendering failed.” error=“failed to send request to remote
> rendering service: Get
> \“http://localhost:8081/render?deviceScaleFactor=1.000000&domain=localhost&encoding=&height=500&renderKey=eAVUw8ofFXRoq03ZzV7ZjB99wlohVbCD&timeout=60&timezone=Asia%2FBangkok&url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fd-solo%2FVTwajYaVz%2Fhome%3ForgId%3D1%26from%3D1678917792848%26to%3D1678939392848%26panelId%3D123125%26width%3D1000%26height%3D500%26tz%3DAsia%252FBangkok%26render%3D1&width=1000\“:
> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8081: connect: connection refused”

try to search the solution but not found

please anyone help me

Comment: Are you running grafana in docker?

Comment: Yes , I run Grafana via docker and run render via NodeJS

Answer (score 2):

The image renderer plugin is incompatible with docker.
You'll have to use another container for the image rendering.

Quote:

> This plugin is not compatible with the current Grafana Docker image and requires additional system-level dependencies. We recommend setting up another Docker container for rendering and using remote rendering instead. For instruction, refer to Run in Docker.

Source: https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-image-renderer/

To setup the separate container, check out the above link or these docs: https://github.com/grafana/grafana-image-renderer#run-in-docker